PHP code works only when the URL has a query "?loggedout=true" in WordPress
I have a PHP code that needs to show the content for only logged in users on WordPress. I used it as a shortcode on some pages. The code looks like below:
<?php
  function my_shortcode_function(){
     if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return 'Please <a href="'.wp_login_url( get_permalink() ).'"><strong>log in</strong></a> to access this page.';
     } else {
        // do something to show content.
     }
  }
  add_shortcode('my_shortcode', 'my_shortcode_function');
?>

But the code works only when the URL has a query of "?loggedout=true".
For example,

if the URL is https://example.com/my_page/, seems the whole code above is ignored and I can't see any output.
If the URL is https://example.com/my_page/?loggedout=true, then it works fine as expected.

I tried to clear my browser cache and no luck.
Is there any reason why the code does work on certain queries?

Note that the callback for shortcodes should return the content, not echo the content. I don't expect this will fix your problem, thought it might.

@Caleb, thanks for your suggestion. I tried that, but it still doesn't work.

Is this on a local setup or server? This looks like a cache issue..not browser, server. Since you pass the query string in the URL and it works, leads me to believe that the server is caching the page, unless you break the cache. Test it by adding any query string to the URL, like ?test=123

What @disinfor is saying makes sense, and is important to understand. Conditional caching can be complicated. My recommendation would be to always render the text, and then either conditionally show or hide it with CSS using logged-in class which is on the root <html> tag.

@disinfor , thanks for your suggestion.
It's running on the server. So, should I find a way to clear the cache on the server?

@ChrisHaas, thanks.
I don't think it's not a solution since the one who knows WordPress and CSS could see the content without login.

FYI: I am voting for your comments. It's helpful ideas though.

Also, can you check this question when you have time and know regex?
It's closed now, but will be opened if it's clear and useful.
Regex Question.

@JShobbyist the best way to handle this, if it is server cache, is to set a caching rule to exclude whatever page you're on. However, if this shortcode can be on any page, then you will have to go the AJAX route to return whatever hidden content needs to be rendered if the user is logged in.

@disinfor, very interesting. Can you give me more details? maybe you can write an answer in detail since comment is not enough to explain.
